# Custom Post type archive_students-list.php and single_students-list.php files not call?

Tags: wordpress

I am using **CPT UI** plugin for custom post type to show students list and i created a page named **Students List** in which i want to show students list.I created **students-list** custom post type as i know if **archive_students-list.php** and **single_students-list.php** files not present then it will call **archive.php** and **single.php** of your current theme but it's not calling.Anyone help me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Permalink Image:

[image]

Comment: can you post WP_Query here? and just update your permalink in settings and try.

Answer (score 0):

When using a custom post type, you don't also create a page to display it. Delete that page and then go to *Settings*->*Permalinks* and hit save to refresh your permalinks. Now, when you go to mysite.com/students-list, your theme will look for and display `archive-students-list.php` (provided that your post type is "students-list", and notice that it's a hyphen, not an underscore).

When you view any individual students-list post, it will display from `single-students-list.php` if that file exists.

With a custom post type, the students-list "page" is automatically created (not in Pages, but dynamically on the fly) and tries to display `archive-students-list.php` if it exists, then `archive.php` if it exists, then ultimately `index.php` if the other two don't exist.

By creating a page, you're confusing WordPress and it's trying to display your page which knows nothing about your students-list post type.

**UPDATE**

Your post type is `projects-list`, not `students-list` so you need `archive-projects-list.php` and `single-projects-list.php` files. Also, be sure that you have created at least one "post" in your projects list or you'll get a 404 error because it will not find any matching "projects".

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: I deleted page as you said and update permalinks first i selected plain and refresh pages then further i set it to post name and go to front-end and hit page but i got page not found error.I attached image for understanding how i created post type through CPT UI plugin.

Comment: Sorry, No luck.Same as you said.I have created two posts inside projects list post type and created both files archive-projects-list.php and single-projects-list.php and hit www.mywebsite.com/projects-list/ but it's showing page not found.

Comment: I also attached permalink image.